# replace specific characters containing "\" character with sed

Tags: sed, quoting

I would like to replace the following sentence "`lw 2,\`" with the sentence "`lw 2`" however I cannot do it with

```
sed -i 's|lw 2,\|lw 2|g' "filname"
```

I get the following error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unterminated `s' command
```

It seems that it doesn't like the "`\`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to escape the backslash:

```
's|lw 2,\\|lw 2|g'
```

Comment: ... because the single backslash would otherwise escape the `|` used (for whatever reason) as a delimiter.